# How to get the bounds of a collection of markers with React-Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How can I get the bounds of a collection of markers, so that these bounds can be used to show all markers on a `react-leaflet` map?
This is my render function:

```
render() {
    const position = [51.505, 4.12];

    return (
        <Map center={position} zoom={3} style={{width: '100%', height: '600px'}} >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />
            {this.state.markers || null}
        </Map>
    );
}
```

The markers are added to `this.state.markers` with:

```
this.state.markers.push(
    <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
            <span>Hello</span>
        </Popup>
    </Marker>
);
this.setState({markers: this.state.markers});
```

The markers are getting displayed, but I want the bounds and centre of the map to be adjusted so the markers fit nicely within the viewport of the map with a certain amount of padding.

Any ideas on how to do this?

*Edit:* This is my import statement: `import {Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet';`

Answer (score 7):

You can add a bounds parameter to the [Map component](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Components.md#map).  It accepts a [leaflet latLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) argument.  So you can do the following:

```
import {latLngBounds} from 'leaflet'

...

render () {
  const bounds = latLngBounds([firstCoord, firstCoord])
  markerData.forEach((data) => {
    bounds.extend(data.latLng)
  })

  return (
    <Map bounds={bounds} >
      ...
    </Map>
  )
}
```

Comment: Would've been much more helpful to know that the latLngBounds function needs a set of coordinates first, using firstCoord two times seems a bit weird...
Also, what is the structure of firstCoord? Is it a latLng object or simply an array with two elements?
Please add the variable firstCoord above the code block :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following function in Angular, but I believe it should work for you as well.

```
fitMapBounds() {
    // Get all visible Markers
    const visibleMarkers = [];
    this.map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            visibleMarkers.push(layer);
        }
    });

    // Ensure there's at least one visible Marker
    if (visibleMarkers.length > 0) {

        // Create bounds from first Marker then extend it with the rest
        const markersBounds = L.latLngBounds([visibleMarkers[0].getLatLng()]);
        visibleMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
            markersBounds.extend(marker.getLatLng());
        });

        // Fit the map with the visible markers bounds
        this.map.flyToBounds(markersBounds, {
            padding: L.point(36, 36), animate: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using hooks, this worked for me

```js
   // example markers
    const markers = [
    [49.8397, 24.0297],
    [52.2297, 21.0122],
    [51.5074, -0.0901],
    [51.4074, -0.0901],
    [51.3074, -0.0901],
   ]

    // hook so this only executes if markers are changed
    // may not need this?

    const bounds = useMemo(() => {
        const b = latLngBounds() // seemed to work without having to pass init arg
        markers.forEach(coords => {
            b.extend(coords)
        })
        return b
    }, [markers])


  ...

  return (
    <Map bounds={bounds} {...rest}> ... </Map>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

create an an array *bounds*, push all coordinates of your markers in there and pass it as props to the map:

```js
import { Map, latLngBound } from "react-leaflet";

const Map = () => {

  const bounds = []

  positions.map((position,i) => {
    bounds.push([position.lat, position.lon])
  })

  return (

    <MapContainer
      bounds={bounds}
    >
    ...
    </MapContainer>

  );
};

export default Map;
```